# difference between "!=" and "not_equal" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When selecting from a `DataFrame`:

Using `not_equal` gives the correct result:

```
d[not_equal(d.something,None)]
```

However using `!=` does not:

```
d[d.something != None]
```

Why is this?

update, d.something dtype('float64'), 
the same is also the case if I try to select NaN values
    d[d.something != nan]

Comment: What is `not_equal` ? (is it `np.not_equal`?)

Comment: @DSM My mistake, thanks for calling me out on that one :) I was confused as I thought PEP8 says test None with is... :s

Comment: could you provide the value of `d.something` in this case?

Comment: yes, not_equal is numpy.not_equal

Comment: What is the value of `d.something`? What is the result of `not_equal(d.something,None)`? What is the result of `d.something != None`?

Comment: d.something is a 'float64', if do d[d.something != None] the result is the same as d. so the None values of d.something is not filtered

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer a bit about "the same is also the case if I try to select NaN values d[d.something != nan]"

You need to be aware that NaN doesn't compare as equal to another NaN:

```
In [40]: numpy.NaN == numpy.NaN
Out[40]: False

In [41]: numpy.NaN != numpy.NaN
Out[41]: True
```

This may seem backwards.  However, when you think of the first along the lines of "if it isn't a number, it can't be equal to anything", it gets more clear.  `==` will always return `False` with `NaN` as either side.  The, if you interpret `a != b` as `not (a == b)`, the second makes sense too.  That could explain part of the problem.  Your `d[d.something != NaN]` will always return `d`.

I will look more into the other issue by digging into the code.